# Drop in a div for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop the image into the div area but i was only able to drag it but it doesn't appear in the div when i have droped it. I wanted to also duplicate the image so that when it is dropped, the original one doesn't disappear.

Javascript code:

```
var dragItem1 = document.getElementById("drag1");
                var dropdiv1 = document.getElementById("div1");

                //event will be fired when a user starts dragging the item
                dragItem1.ondragstart = function (evt) {
                    evt.dataTransfer.setData('key1', evt.target.id);
                    console.log("its dragging..");
                }

                //event will be fired when an element is selected and dragged over a drop location
                dropdiv1.ondragover = function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    console.log("it's dragover..");
                }

                //event will be fired when you drop dragged item on drop location
                dropdiv1.ondrop = function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var dropItem1 = evt.dataTransfer.getData('key1');
                    console.log(evt);
                    console.log("its dropped..");
                    console.log(dropItem1);
                    var myElement1 = document.getElementById(dropItem1);
                    console.log(myElement1);
                    var myNewElement = document.createElement('img');
                    myNewElement.src = myElement1.src;
                    console.log(myNewElement);
                }
```

HTML code:

```
<img id="drag1" draggable="true" src="images/equation1_3.png">

<div class="boxFirstCol box1 b1 box" id="div1" ondrop="ondrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
```

Comment: You never add the element to your drop div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(myNewElement);` to add the element to the drop location.

```js
var dragItem1 = document.getElementById("drag1");
                var dropdiv1 = document.getElementById("div1");

                //event will be fired when a user starts dragging the item
                dragItem1.ondragstart = function (evt) {
                    evt.dataTransfer.setData('key1', evt.target.id);
                    
                }

                //event will be fired when an element is selected and dragged over a drop location
                dropdiv1.ondragover = function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                  
                }

                //event will be fired when you drop dragged item on drop location
                dropdiv1.ondrop = function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    var dropItem1 = evt.dataTransfer.getData('key1');
                   
                    var myElement1 = document.getElementById(dropItem1);
                    console.log(myElement1);
                    var myNewElement = document.createElement('img');
                    var myNewElement
                    myNewElement.src = myElement1.src;
                    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(myNewElement);

                }
```

```html
<img id="drag1" draggable="true" src="http://www.icon2s.com/img64/64x64-animal-icon-hamster.png">

<div style="background-color:red;width:200px;height:200px;" id="div1" ondrop="ondrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.appendChild()` to append the dynamically created `<img>` element to `event.target` within `drop` event handler.

```
dropdiv1.ondrop = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var dropItem1 = evt.dataTransfer.getData('key1');
  console.log(evt);
  console.log("its dropped..");
  console.log(dropItem1);
  var myElement1 = document.getElementById(dropItem1);
  console.log(myElement1);
  var myNewElement = document.createElement('img');
  myNewElement.src = myElement1.src;
  console.log(myNewElement);
  evt.target.appendChild(myNewElement); // append `<img>` to `<div>`
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OndnpzsIJjTjhbiNbhUc?p=preview